# Questions about loading files in a program

Tags: java, file, load, filereader, file-format

Sup!

I'm trying to understand the concepts and differences between them to load and save files, and trying to figure out the best way to load files with a program I'm making (a database). I'm using Java, but try to help me in a more general way, if possible. Whatever help I get is a lot welcome and I thank you already for it.

1. I know there is "File Reader" in Java and a lot of programs use files in .txt format. I tried to open a .doc file with Notepad, just to see what would happen, and NOTHING was a text. I expected that, not everything though.
   I just don't know how to make a file that is not a .txt. How that happens?
2. This is a big one. When I load a file, should I load all its content and let it ready for use, or should I just keep the file path and read from it as I use, using offsets and pointers starting from the file path? How should I do this either way?
3. In this database program of mine, some things will be images (for example), and if I were to use a .txt, I would give each image a label that the program would read and then interpret it like the label of the image, and then get the image. How could I do that?

I was sure I had more questions. If I do I ask again.

Once more, thanks in advance for the attention and help.

Comment: 1. You need to use a library capable of reading `.doc` files. There's nothing in the standard Java SDK to do this, as there is nothing special about `.doc` files over any other file format: it's just a stream of bytes.

Comment: I'm looking to read a .doc file, that was an example.
.pdf, .cad, .doc, .ppt files, etc are not .txt.

How do I make a file that is not a .txt? That was the meant question. =P
I know they are a bunch of bytes that mean something to the correct program. I just don't know how they are done.

Comment: There is nothing special about my comment mentioning `doc`: you need a library capable of reading the file's format; you will likely need a different library to read each format since those listed are very different.

Comment: [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org) might be of interest.

Comment: Got it Andy. Thanks for the info, dude.
Now, what if I want to make my own file?
I would have to create a library for it, right?

Answer (score -1):

When it comes to the .txt bit, all "plain text" will work. Just change the file extension to .ini or .sql (if sql is installed) and change it in your filepath too.

Comment: I know it can be worked up using plain text. I just don't know how. Take the image example, for example. lol

Comment: But I can put a bunch of images as resources for the program and get it to load those images when a certain text is read.

For example, say the database is about cars.
For the manufacturer, I want to display the image of the company.
So the .txt file goes:
"Car - Vectra;
 Color - Black;
 Manufacturer - Chevrolet;"
When the program reads the word "Chevrolet" from the "Manufacturer" entry, it will load and display accordingly the image of the company that goes by Chevrolet.

Don't know how to do that. Or if it would be easier to use another type of file format.

Comment: @Werneck you want to use a textfile to store filepaths to the images you want to load?

Comment: That could be it, but I'd still prefer my way of using the program to translate a word in a specific entry into an image inside a resource folder, or something like that.

Comment: @Werneck Okay, I see what you want now. You can achieve this with a text file. However it would be unneccesarily much effort. You will have to use a lot of string manipulation. Easier would be to use another format, like json. Google around a bit for how a json file looks like, how its build up. There are libraries availeble to deserialize (turn a json file into a java object (so you can use object.color) or serialize(turn object into a json file).

Comment: Thanks a lot, wasted. I'll look into that! =D